# update offline cache w/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, offline-caching

I have a site that fetches content with Ajax.

Would it be possible to do this:

1) upon first request get some data and store in offline cache (I know this one can be done)

2) fetch additional data with ajax and add that to the offline cache storage, so that next time user fires browser to my url without a working internet connection, the most recently fetched data will be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible.

you can do this by.

- first read the content that is sotred in cache.
  (stored content is in key value pair)

you can do this by

```
var storeObj = window.localStorage;
var string = storeObj.getItem(storeKey);
```

// this will be string

parse it into json if you want that.

```
                json = JSON.parse(string);
```

* now append yor result as by string or by json.

```
// if by json
json["item"] = "newvalue";
```

- now clear storage by key

  ```
  storeObj.removeItem(storeKey);
  ```
- now store back this new json to cache

  ```
  storeObj.setItem(storeKey, JSON.stringify(json));
  ```